# How to iterate through a JSON string in jsp page using jstl tags?

Tags: java, json, jsp, jstl

I have this JSON string hich comes from the servlet`session.setAttribute("leavesJson", leavesJson);` and now I'm trying to print it on JSP page.

JSON String:

```
{"7:[{"ID":7,"Req":6,
"Type":1,"dataAi":null,"dataA":null,"dataR":null,"nrZ":null}],
"8":[{"ID":8,"Req":11,"Type":2,"dataA":null,"dataAi":null,"dataR":null,"nrZ":null}]}
```

In JSP page I have this:

```
<c:set var="leavesJson" value="leavesJsonForTL"/>
    <c:if test="${empty leavesJsonForTL.leavesTeam}">

        <c:out value="${leavesJson}"/>
        <c:forEach begin="0" end="${leavesJson.length() -1}" var="leavesJsonForTL"> 

               //what should I put here? 

        </c:forEach>

    </c:if>
```

I want to print all the details from that JSON and don't really know how to proceed. How to access that elements from the string?.

Comment: Why would you expose it as a string? Expose objects, or do it via JS.

Comment: Expose as an object would be the preferred way. But you could also use http://json-taglib.sourceforge.net/